# How to strikethrough in PyCharm comments?

Tags: pycharm, formatting, markdown, comments

[JetBrains' doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/markdown-syntax.html) claims that

> Strikethrough | ~~Never mind~~ | <s>Never mind</s>

is supported.

However, it doesn't work.

[image]

What am I missing?

---

EDIT:

It appears I read the wrong docs, for markdown files.

I am still looking for strikethrough in comments.

Comment: Those docs appear to be for markdown files, not comments. Those docs are also for a program called "Upstream".

Comment: Why do you think strikethrough is supported in comments?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Looks like Googling this got me nothing. Maybe it isn't supported?

Comment: @jonrsharpe becasue it is 2021 and JetBrains have good products. But if it doesn't exist, you can just say so :)

Answer (score 3):

You can kind-of achieve what you want. Go into the settings and search for `TODO`. You'll find a "TODO" menu. You can click the `+` to add another pattern rule:

[image]

Now, any line that begins with `strike` will be stricken-out in red:

[image]

I believe this is as good as you'll be able to get.

Notes:

- Yes, the strike line is very faint. I don't know if there's a way of boldening it.
- You must restart Pycharm after creating the rule for it to work.
- I do not know what `\b` and `.*` are for. Skip whitespace when pattern matching? That may be regex, and I'm awful with regex.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, but I was looking for something built-in that I can scale to the rest of the team without having to configure Pycharm for everyone. Well it is what it is, thanks :)